# Is there a way to send files in body using OWASP ZAP?

Tags: security, owasp, zap

In order to test something like, file upload (Content-Type: multipart/form-data), is there functionality in OWASP ZAP to send a file in a request body?

I've tried copy pasting the contents of the file but that didn't work out of the box. Using curl's flag `-F 'file=@foobar.pdf'`, did work, but I'd like to get it working in ZAP.

Help much appreciated!

EDIT:

Also the error I'm getting when copy-pasting the contents of a file is:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "detail": "Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None"
  }
}
```

Comment: If the message is properly crafted it should work. Specify a proper boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZAP doesnt have any specific option to make it easy for you, but if you craft it right then it will work. To see what the request should look like proxy the curl request through ZAP.